# SQL: Create multiple rows for a record based on months between two dates

Tags: sql, netezza

My table has records as below for different Id's and different start and end dates
ID,  Startdate,  Enddate
1,   2017-02-14, 2018-11-05

I want to write an SQL **without** using date dimension table that gives below output: Basically one record for each month between start and end date.

```
1, 2017, 02
1, 2017, 03
1, 2017, 04
1, 2017, 05
1, 2017, 06
1, 2017, 07
1, 2017, 08
1, 2017, 09
1, 2017, 10
1, 2017, 11
1, 2017, 12
1, 2018, 01
1, 2018, 02
1, 2018, 03
1, 2018, 04
1, 2018, 05
1, 2018, 06
1, 2018, 07
1, 2018, 09
1, 2018, 10
1, 2018, 11
```

Comment: Can you add more sample data?  I don't see the connect between the single record you showed us and the expected output table.

Comment: Basically one record for each month between start and end date.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Netezza?  Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: I am using Netezza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked like a charm:

```
-- sample data  
WITH table_data
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id
        ,cast('2017-08-14' AS DATE) AS start_dt
        ,cast('2018-12-16' AS DATE) AS end_dt

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS id
    ,cast('2017-09-14' AS DATE) AS start_dt
    ,cast('2019-01-16' AS DATE) AS end_dt
)

-- find minimum date from the data  
,starting_date (start_date)
AS (
SELECT min(start_dt)
FROM TABLE_DATA
)

--get all months between min and max dates  
,all_dates
AS (
SELECT last_day(add_months(date_trunc('month', start_date), idx * 1)) month_date
FROM starting_date
CROSS JOIN _v_vector_idx
WHERE month_date <= add_months(start_date, abs(months_between((
                    SELECT min(start_dt) FROM TABLE_DATA), (SELECT max(end_dt) FROM TABLE_DATA))) + 1)
ORDER BY month_date
)
SELECT id  
,extract(year FROM month_date)  
,extract(month FROM month_date)  
,td.start_dt  
,td.end_dt  
FROM table_data td  
INNER JOIN all_dates ad  
    ON ad.month_date > td.start_dt  
        AND ad.month_date <= last_day(td.end_dt)  
ORDER BY 1  
    ,2
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query example:

```
set @start_date = '2017-02-14';
set @end_date = LAST_DAY('2018-11-05');


WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS
(
select MONTH(@start_date) as month_, YEAR(@start_date) as year_, DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as next_month_date
UNION
SELECT MONTH(dr.next_month_date) as month_, YEAR(dr.next_month_date) as year_, DATE_ADD(dr.next_month_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as next_month_date
FROM date_range dr
where next_month_date <= @end_date
)
select month_, year_ from date_range 
order by next_month_date desc
```

Comment: there are multiple records with different start and end date. I just gave an example of 1 record

Comment: Can you please provide table name, so according to that i can give you complete query solution. because for this solution, it doesn't matter either one record or any more.

Comment: table name is "DATA". It has 3 fields ID, STARTDT, ENDDT. There are different IDs that have different start and end dates.

Comment: and recursive queries are not supported in Netezza

Comment: This answer worked like a charm, is standard SQL and performs very fast.  This should be the accepted answer.  The other answer uses group and order by functions to work which will cause implicit temporary tables and less scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate date and from that have to pick year and month

```
select distinct year(date),month( date) from
(select  * from (
select 
 date_add('2017-02-14 00:00:00.000', INTERVAL n5.num*10000+n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) as date 
  from
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n1,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n2,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n3,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n4,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n5
) a
where date >'2017-02-14 00:00:00.000' and date < '2018-11-05'
) as t
```

Comment: without using dimension

Comment: date dimension table has date field and you need to pick month and year from that

Comment: we do not have date dimension table.

Comment: what if my table has 2 rows?

Comment: ID, Startdate, Enddate  
1, 2017-02-14, 2018-11-05  
2, 2018-03-11, 2018-08-16

Comment: then you need to correct your design because 2nd date duration is already covrred by 1st